# Append FMDB SQLite results to Swift array

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite, xcode6, fmdb

I'm trying to append results from a FMDB SQLite query to a Swift array.  The error I'm getting in XCode is 'value of option type 'String?' not unwrapped.'

Swapping out the line below in the while loop, the FMDB results can be printed to console OK, so no problems there.

```
println(results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test"))
```

New to XCode, so be kind...

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tests_label: UILabel!

    var databasePath = NSString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var arrayData:[String] = []



        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("vmd_db.db")

        let myDatabase = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if myDatabase.open(){

            let query_lab_test = "SELECT lab_test FROM lab_test"

            let results_lab_test:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(query_lab_test, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results_lab_test?.next() == true {
                if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test"){
                arrayData.append(resultString)
                    var multiLineString = join("\n", arrayData)
                    tests_label.text = multiLineString
                    tests_label.numberOfLines = 0
                    tests_label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
                    tests_label.sizeToFit()

            }

        }
    }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**Working Code thanks to @skypecakes:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tests_label: UILabel!

    var databasePath = NSString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("vmd_db.db")

        let myDatabase = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if myDatabase.open(){

            var arrayData:[String] = []

            let query_lab_test = "SELECT lab_test FROM lab_test"

            let results_lab_test:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(query_lab_test, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results_lab_test?.next() == true {

                if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test"){

                arrayData.append(resultString)

            }
        }
            println(arrayData)
            myDatabase.close()
    }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like 
`results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test")`
returns a String?, which is an optional. Your array is defined as an array of "String" items, so you can't put a "String?" inside it.
Try this:

```
if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test")
    arrayData.append(resultString)
```

Note that in general it is good practice to unwrap all of your optionals with "if let" instead of assuming that they are populated. So everywhere you have a question mark (e.g. results_lab_test?.stringForColumn), you can use "if let".

If you're using XCode 7 with Swift 2.0, this would be a good case for the "guard let" statement, which provides a convenient syntax to abort your code if an optional returns null:

```
guard let queryResults = results_lab_test else return
while queryResults.next() == true {
if let resultString = queryResults.stringForColumn("lab_test")
        arrayData.append(resultString)
}
```

This test worked for me (table has 2 rows, and printing the array prints 2 rows), in case it helps you:

```
import UIKit
import FMDB

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let myDatabase = makeSqlDB()
        {
            var arrayData:[String] = []
            let query_lab_test = "SELECT lab_test FROM lab_test"

            let results_lab_test:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(query_lab_test, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results_lab_test?.next() == true
            {
                if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test")
                {
                    arrayData.append(resultString)
                }
            }

            println(arrayData)
            myDatabase.close()
        }
    }


    private func makeSqlDB()->FMDatabase?
    {
        let database = FMDatabase(path: String())

        if !database.open() {
            println("Unable to open database")
            return nil
        }

        if !database.executeUpdate("create table lab_test(lab_test text)", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
            println("create table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if !database.executeUpdate("insert into lab_test (lab_test) values (?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["test1"]) {
            println("insert 1 table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if !database.executeUpdate("insert into lab_test (lab_test) values (?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["test2"]) {
            println("insert 2 table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        return database
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fills the array. However I get the same number of sets of data as there are records in the table (ie 812 sets of 812 records...).  Using XCode 6.4.

Comment: Glad to hear your original problem is fixed. It would help if you describe the expected behavior. What do you expect to be in the result set, and what do you want the resulting array to contain, exactly? What does the table look like? From your code it looks like there is a table named lab_test which contains a column named lab_test, which seems a bit odd but could happen.

Comment: Yes, the column should be called lab_test_name or similar, but at the moment it's 'lab_test'.  The table 'lab_test' contains 812 records.  I want to put all of the records using just the lab_test column into the array and eventually have them listed on separate lines in an interface widget.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of putting the results into an array, how would I print the records on separate lines to the main interface?  If I say make a label.text = to the results, I just get the one line in the label...

Comment: Can you post your entire method and also the method from which it is called? It sounds like there may be a loop within a loop occurring. To print on separate lines, you'll need to loop through the results just like with the array, and append a newline character plus the next result for each iteration through the loop. Also be sure to set the label's Lines property to 0. And if you're using autolayout you may need to tweak it to allow the label to grow.

Comment: Updated the question with all the ViewController code.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for populating a label, as that is pretty different from your original problem/question. If you are still having issues populating the array, please update your question with the current behavior you are seeing and how you would like it to work. I did a quick test and the code you have should populate the array with 1 item per row in your table. If you are getting more than that, is it possible your table contains more items than you expect?

Comment: @skypecakes..I modified my code with your changes as necessary and it printed the array without duplication.   many thanks for your help.  I'll open another question about printing the results to a label or similar instead of the console.